# "This website is asking to store data on your computer for offline use"

Tags: firefox, browser-cache, html5, offline-files, local-storage

Whenever I visit some websites using Firefox, I get the dialog below asking me to "store data on your computer for offline use".

[image]

It is displayed if I am using Firefox but not if I am using Chrome.

Why does it show up? What does it mean? What is this data storage? How is it different from the browser cache? Why does FF display it but Chrome doesn't?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2, Firefox 23.0 and Chromium 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 12.04 (28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.12.04.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website is asking for permission to use the [HTML5 Offline Web Applications API](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/#introduction):

> Users of typical online Web applications are only able to use the applications while they have a connection to the Internet. When they go offline, they can no longer check their e-mail, browse their calendar appointments, or prepare presentations with their online tools. Meanwhile, native applications provide those features: e-mail clients cache folders locally, calendars store their events locally, presentation packages store their data files locally.
>
> In addition, while offline, users are dependent on their HTTP cache to obtain the application at all, since they cannot contact the server to get the latest copy.
>
> The HTML 5 specification provides two solutions to this: a SQL-based database API for storing data locally, and an offline application HTTP cache for ensuring applications are available even when the user is not connected to their network.

[Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) explains further:

> At its simplest, an offline web application is a list of URLs — HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images, or any other kind of resource. The home page of the offline web application points to this list, called a manifest file, which is just a text file located elsewhere on the web server. A web browser that implements HTML5 offline applications will read the list of URLs from the manifest file, download the resources, cache them locally, and automatically keep the local copies up to date as they change. When the time comes that you try to access the web application without a network connection, your web browser will automatically switch over to the local copies instead.

As you've noticed, this is separate from the normal browser cache. They serve two different purposes; the browser cache is used to speed up access to commonly used resources, while this is used to store offline web applications and their resources.

It seems that Chrome allows webapps to store themselves offline without user permission. Firefox, on the other hand, asks for permission before allowing webapps to use the offline APIs.

Answer (score -2):

it wants you to "download" this page so it can be watched without internet connection
sometimes not all the page but something long to load

Comment: No, that is not true. Don't confuse it with caching.

Comment: caching downloads things slow to load like images, this asks to open the page or the app withou connection, not?

Comment: Well, no, not entirely. tapped-out's answer explains this very well.

Comment: i know, but the question wasn't answered for a lot time, so i put here my little knowledge, i din't espected an entire book froom tapped-out :(